# Power BI Generate a new ID when a row has a particular value

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a table which has captured multiple actions taken by users for one Application. A single application can be submitted, rejected, and accepted multiple times. For this process I would like to generate a single ID. However, after the application has been accepted, the user can resubmit the same application ID and I want to generate a new ID for this submission. Below is my table which has been pre-processed: [image: Application Process Table]

The tabled has been grouped by the "Application ID" and sorted by "Date". I created a conditional column that flags when the start of a new submission: "Is New Submission". When "Previous User Action" = *Accept* and "User Action" = *Resubmit*, this would indicate as *True* (highlighted blue). My goal is to create the "Desired Submission ID" column. When the user submits the application the first time, an ID is generated. And after it's been Accepted and Resubmitted again, this would generate a new ID. Is this achievable with DAX? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ids 001, 002... 00N is per Application ID right? And when there are Accept & Resubmit in the same row, it should produce a new id right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Can you comment on what Desired Submission Id is used for? Remember that DAX and Power BI are reporting tools only. The only use I can see for this new field is for a distinct count.

Comment: It seems that this is something easily achieved in M.  (Power Query).   Why use DAX here?

Comment: The Desired Submission ID is the column that I am trying to achieve. It will be used to create several measurements on the submission level (e.g. # of days until accepted per submission) rather than counting per record/row.

The reason I'm asking for DAX is because I've noticed my M queries run very long with this dataset. I would love to see your solution with M. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in M Code.

I assumed that the data was sorted by Date as you show.
 Also, this code is just for the single Application ID. Your real data probably has multiple Application IDs, so I would expect you would `Group By` that ID and adapt the code below into an aggregation function for the `Group By`

Finally, the table I am working from is only your columns 1,2,3 and 5 (I assume those are original data and column 4 is calculated by you from that.

***Data***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//determine Submission ID using List.Generate to loop through the datetime sorted list
//If you have Grouped by Application ID, need to have this as an aggregation
    offsetList = List.Transform(
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[sid=1, idx=0],
            each [idx]<Table.RowCount(Source),
            each [sid=if Source[User Action]{[idx]+1} = "Accept" and Source[User Action]{[idx]} = "Resubmit" 
                    then [sid]+1 else [sid], idx=[idx]+1],
            each [sid]), 
                each Number.ToText(_,"000")),

//add submission ID as new column
    subID = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Source) & {offsetList},
        type table
            [Index=Int64.Type, Application ID=Int64.Type, Date = DateTime.Type, User Action=Text.Type, Desired Submission ID = Text.Type]
    )

in
    subID
```

***Results***
[image]